How to deal with multiple events from IR remote control?
I am trying to capture events from an IR remote control in a python loop. I am using the evdev lib
Here is my code :
import evdev
def get_ir_device():
    devices = [evdev.InputDevice(path) for path in evdev.list_devices()]
    for device in devices:
        if (device.name == "gpio_ir_recv"):
            print("Using device", device.path, "n")
            return device
    print("No device found!")

dev = get_ir_device()

while(True):
    event = dev.read_one()
    if (event):
       if  (event.value==10):
         do something

the problem is the event is triggered several times (and not only one) when I click on the button (keystroke=10).
The script
ir-keytable -t 

does the same thing but the events are displayed alternately with the mark "toggle" or with a blank mark to identify events associated with the same physical click, which makes it easier to deal with. I found no attribute named "toggle" in the event object.
My question : how can I get rid off these multiple events.
Hope my msg is clear. Not easy to phrase it.
PS : i tried to change the delay and period values with ir-keytable -D and -P options unsuccessfully
PS2 : my test is based on :Ignorant of Things
PS3 : adding a time.sleep period in the loop changed nothing. It's like events were bufferized, they just come out after the sleep period.

Here's how I did it on an Asus PN51.
It is not a Raspberry Pi question, it applies to any computer with Linux (a recent kernel) and an infrared receiver.
timer = 0.0
tolerance = 2 # Max seconds for events to be considered duplicates

for event in dev.read_loop():
    if timer == 0.0 or time.time() > timer + tolerance:
        timer = time.time()
        # Process event.value
     # No else, just ignore the button press

This is an extension of my shutdown script at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/753802/321108

I am not advocating a sleep, just some timing code, so that events that are close together (2 seconds in my example) are ignored. Forgive me if I have misread your code - it would be better to put it, properly formatted, in the question.

P.S. I completely misread your postscripts. PS1, PS2 and PS3 mean something completely different to us Linux types!

you are right, what you wrote works perfectly. The issue comes from the screen update: I'd like to display date and time in an oled screen. So I need to draw text in the loop. something like         oled.image(image_bw)
draw.text((55,2),time_var,font=font1,size=1,fill=0)    oled.show(). I tried to put these lines in a while true: loop and afterwards I added your code. But it doesn't work correctly. Maybe I can do with threads but I'd prefer not.

I rephrased my pb in a new question : https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/149309/how-to-update-the-display-of-an-oled-screen-and-receive-ir-events-in-the-same-lo

A separate challenge I had was that the device reader requires root access, but I wanted to display to the logged-in user's X window session. If you want help with this, please raise a separate question, but NOT on the Pi site  - use Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/ ) or Unix & Linux (https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ).

This code can retrieve any IR key pressed with no artefacts and an allowed delay of 1 second :
import time
import evdev
    
def get_ir_device():
        devices = [evdev.InputDevice(path) for path in evdev.list_devices()]
        for device in devices:
            if (device.name == "gpio_ir_recv"):           
                return device          
    dev = get_ir_device()
    
    
 def trig_ir(arg):
    event = dev.read_one()
    result=None
    if (event) :
        a = event.value
        if not(a==0):
            result= a
            arg[3]=0
        else:
            if arg[3]==1:
                result=a
                arg[3]=0
            else:
                result=None
                arg[3]=1
    else:
        arg[3]=0
    if not(result==None):
        last_result=result
        arg[2] = time.perf_counter()
        if not(last_result==arg[0]) or (arg[2]-arg[1])>1:
            arg[1] = time.perf_counter()
            arg[0]=last_result
            return result
                 
IR_param=[-100,time.perf_counter(),0,0]
    
while True:
    key=trig_ir(IR_param)
    if not(key==None):    
      print(key) 

